# React-Router 1.0 - Nested UI Components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a nested component in a react router.

My goal is to have this nested component be a container for other components. I am trying to setup a wizard so the components can change depending on the route

Is react-router capable of something like this?

Comment: What do you mean with "have these components be determined by the other"? Component nesting works by default via Route definition and the nesting of the routes.

Comment: @larrydahooster I made an edit, hopefully its a bit clearer now.

Comment: Yeah, much clearer now. But it would also be nice to share some of your efforts, as by now my only answer would be: Yes, it is capable of doing so.

Comment: I achieved my goal by manually changing the url using window.location.hash and then setting an event listener that listens to a hashchange. When this event listener is fired, I manually update the react component using setState()